# Can't get my webapp accessible using eclipse, apache2 and tomcat7 (Ubuntu)

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, servlets, ubuntu

I'm quite a rookie about servlets, but I should deploy an Eclipse web project running on a Tomcat server (only localhost).
The whole process worked fine on Windows but recently I had to move to Ubuntu 12.04 and I have this problem when I want to access the app:

If I start apache2 and tomcat7 first, the output of

> sudo netstat -lpn |grep :80

looks like this:

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12231/apache2
>   tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      12848/java
>   tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      12848/java

then I try to start the server in eclipse and face this error:

> Several ports (8005, 8080) required by cdrserver are already in use. The server may already >be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this >server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

Alright, let's kill these processes (although it seems that Tomcat uses them since when i stop tomcat, the 2 tcp6 processes disappear).

Now I'm able to start the Eclipse server, without a single warning:

> Nov 27, 2013 10:59:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>
> INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
>
> Nov 27, 2013 10:59:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>
> INFO: Initialization processed in 869 ms
>
> Nov 27, 2013 10:59:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
>
> INFO: Starting service Catalina
>
> Nov 27, 2013 10:59:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
>
> INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
>
> Nov 27, 2013 10:59:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
>
> INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/aron/workspace/Text_manipulator
>
> Nov 27, 2013 10:59:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
>
> INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/aron/workspace/.metadata
>
> Nov 27, 2013 10:59:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
>
> INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/aron/workspace/Servers
>
> Nov 27, 2013 10:59:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>
> INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
>
> Nov 27, 2013 10:59:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>
> INFO: Server startup in 2101 ms

Now, if I type the usual (like on Windows) URL to the browser: localhost/cdr I get this:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /cdr was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Same happens with localhost/manager (I got this tip lately).

Moreover, using localhost:8080/cdr results in a totally blank page.

Here are my Eclipse server settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB7CI.png

I also checked the web.xml file in the project, it has the following servlet classes and related mappings:

- Faces Servlet
- Trinidad Resource Servlet
- Resources Servlet
- Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I can't see any project/directory named `cdr` deployed in the logs. Can you verify that this particular resource is present in the deployment folder webapps/wtpwebapps ?

Comment: No, the wtpwebapps folder only contains a ROOT/WEB.INF/web.xml structure, xml content is 3 lines with a detailed web-app tag. Is there a possible way to make up for the missing resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The requested URL /cdr was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Firstly your URL should be something like `localhost:8080` , Not `localhost` since this defaults to `localhost:80` and you have apache2 running on your system thats why you get the 404 message of the apache server.

Secondly , I am concerned about the resources being deployed as shown by your logs

```
Nov 27, 2013 10:59:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/aron/workspace/Text_manipulator
Nov 27, 2013 10:59:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
**INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/aron/workspace/.metadata** --> ?
Nov 27, 2013 10:59:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
**INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/aron/workspace/Servers** --> ?
Nov 27, 2013 10:59:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
```

What is *.metadata* ? Isn't this one of the hidden folders created by eclipse to manage workspace. This shouldn't be deployed.

Also what is *Servers* ? This looks like the server project from eclipse.

I don't see any resource namely `cdr` being deployed from the logs. So first you need to verify that this particular resource is deployed at all. Secondly, I would advise you to do some reading on how Tomcat works [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheTomcat/article.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, beginning from the tutorial you sent I managed to grab a hold on the app finally!

Comment: Glad I was able to help